# Stored procedure does not recognize the table name, using schema

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am looking to implement Schema. SQL

1. all my table names begin with `SchemaName.TableName`
2. When I login to SQL Server using the user name and password for the schema, and do a `Select` on one of the tables, I get back a result set.
3. When I have the same `select` inside a stored procedure, when I execute this stored procedure, it does not recognize the table name. The execution fails.

Would this be an issue with SQL Server 2008

Please suggest

Thank you,

Comment: What are the details of the failure?

Comment: Is the stored procedure in the same schema?

Comment: Bouncing off of @M.Ali, if not in the same schema, make sure the proper grants are given, or synonyms are created

Comment: `using the user name and password for the schema` - schemas don't have user names and passwords. They have *owners*, and those owners may have *logins* associated with them, and those logins will have usernames and *may* have passwords, but that's a long way away from a schema having a user name and password.